# What is the elegant way to handle interruptions on IO?

Tags: java, io

I am looking at implementation of `IOUtils.copy()` from Apache Commons at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java.html and it eventually boils down to:

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    // DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE is 4096
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    long count = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I am running this in an `Executor`, the task has a timeout etc. but if I understand correctly even if it times out and the `Future` is cancelled, the thread keeps on running because there is no check for thread status anywhere in this loop. This leads to a dangerous leak and starvation.

Seems like I need to rewrite the loop, but what is the sane and correct way to handle this? `throw new IOException(new InterruptedException())`? Declare the method as throwing `InterruptedException` and throw it (hate to do it for all my IO helper methods)?

***EDIT***: I just checked `ByteStreams` from Guava and they seem to be doing the same thing. Now I'm wondering why the two major libraries don't support interruptions in such loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: The real answer to this issue seems to be using NIO. It appears to react to thread interruptions properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you close `input` and/or `output`, the `copyLarge` method will throw an exception, exiting the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that's one way to break free.

Answer (score 1):

For any blocking I/O (ie, the java.io package), you would have to check this manually and do something in response to it.

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { 
    // do something here to stop processing
}
```

If you're using the channels (java.nio), you don't have to do this.  Any thread interrupted issued during one of the NIO operations would cause that operation to throw a ClosedByInterruptException.